# Pythonic web-based framework other than Django

Tags: django

I totally agree that Django rocks since I have been involved in lot of Django myself. Just for having more frameworks under my belt, I thought it would be great to learn another pythonic web application framework.

Any suggestions here ?

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: Googling "list of python web frameworks" would have given you @Ignacio's list

Comment: A "Why" in the answers would be nice. I don't know the poster, but I can get google results just fine. SO I trust to give me insights on why should I consider one product over the other.

Comment: @darioo: Yes, Googling would have given me the list of those frameworks. I am interested more in weighing the experience of the community who have indulged in those frameworks practically. That would give a better judgement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Django can be treat already as standard solution for Python web frameworks ;)

But If you are looking for something new - try http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/ Werkzeug, it's like framework for building frameworks.. If you will get familiar with Werkzeug, all frameworks will be open for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try [web2py](http://web2py.com/). It has all batteries included :-)

Answer (score 2):

this is a list http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

i guess Pylons and web2py are good options

Answer (score 1):

[Zope](http://www.zope.org/) would be a cool framework to learn. Zope community is very active, as is the case with Django.

Also, venturing on ERP5 would be an interesting learning curve.

NOTE: Can only post 1 hyperlink. So, please google on ERP5 to know about it.